# File reading problem after installing cv2 [Python]

Tags: python, file, opencv

I'm a begginer, and I wanted to learn OpenCV in python, so I installed it by PIP

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

The first program I made using the libary dosen't worked, it displays an error that was raised by imread() method:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I checked a couple of times, and both file and directory exists!

After some time I tried running a diffrent program I made before, that reads files by read() method, and it showed up the same error, it was working before I installed cv2, and i haven't changed it by this time.

Maybe there's something in the code so there are both of these:

```
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread('/Desktop/uczemsiemprogramowacniepaczec/zdjencia/artest.jpg')

cv.imshow('window', img)

cv.waitKey(0)
#this is the first program, it is supposed to show artest.jpg in a diffrent window
```

the second one:

```
import keyboard
import time
print("five seconds till spam")
time.sleep(5)
P = open("C:/Users/tymon/Desktop/E/wpisza.txt")
T = P.readlines()
P.close()
for i in T:
 keyboard.press_and_release('enter')
 time.sleep(1)
 keyboard.write(i.replace("\n", ""))
 keyboard.press_and_release('enter')
 #this was supposed to send an entire wpisza.png file in the chat
```

Finally, sorry for possible bad english (it is not my native language)

I searched for the solution to this problem everywhere on the Internet, and I haven't found any, so I hope someone knows this...

Comment: Most likely the problem is with the relative path `'/Desktop/uczemsiemprogramowacniepaczec/zdjencia/artest.jpg'` - I doubt you really have this 3-level deep folder structure in your current working directory (cwd). What is your cwd you run the files from?

Comment: Probably, wrong file path is given.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so first, I would **check the path again, maybe left click on your image, see properties** and check the path there. Also, try to **use relative paths**. **Your path is always FROM your file.** So if your path is **/Project/main.py** and your image is in **/Project/test_images/t1.jpeg** your code will be:

```
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread('./test_images/t1.jpeg')

cv.imshow('window', img)

cv.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: I replaced the path with a new one from properties, and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: Glad it did! Then please mark my answer as the solution. :)